# mkdir making files in intended location and desktop

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I am making a script that will make a folder and sub-folders based off a template. I creates the file in the intended location, but it also splits all files on the desktop.

```
echo off
cls
echo Type The SO number, Customer, and Job named when asked. Then press Enter
echo.
set /p SO="SO #: "
set /p Customer="Customer Name: "
set /p JOB="Job Name: "
set folder="%SO%"_"%Customer%"_"%JOB%"
echo %folder%
set dir="F:\Sales\User 1\_QUOTES"
set final="%dir%\%folder%"
set dst="%final%/1 - Estimating Original Quote Material"
if not exist %final% (
    mkdir "%dst%"
    copy /-Y "%dir%\_takeoff.xlsx" %dst%
    mkdir "%dst%\Downloads"
    mkdir "%dst%\Plans"
    mkdir "%dst%\Quotes"
    mkdir "%dst%\Cut Sheets"
    mkdir "%dst%\Venders"
    mkdir "%final%\2 - Signed Quote - Contract\Non-Current Purchase Orders"
    mkdir "%final%\3 - Special Purchase Trading Goods"
    mkdir "%final%\4 - Engineering\2 - Submittals"
    mkdir "%final%\4 - Engineering\3 - Approvals"
    mkdir "%final%\4 - Engineering\4 - Drawings in Progress\Released Production Drawings"
    mkdir "%final%\5 - Final Production Drawings"
    mkdir "%final%\6 - Q.C. Document"
    mkdir "%final%\7 - Project Management _ Schedule"   
) 
pause
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean when you say it splits all files on the destkop?

Comment: I sends parts of folder to the Sales folder, and multiple files on the user desktop

Comment: How about you visit your earlier question and modify the code according to the syntax given to you in the answers there, before submitting code which clearly has not followed the advice provided!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed and streamlined some things:

```
@echo off

echo Type The SO number, Customer, and Job named when asked. Then press Enter.
echo.
set /p "SO=SO #: "
set /p "Customer=Customer Name: "
set /p "JOB=Job Name: "

set "folder=%SO%_%Customer%_%JOB%"
echo %folder%
set "dir=F:\Sales\User 1\_QUOTES"
set "final=%dir%\%folder%"
set "dst=%final%\1 - Estimating Original Quote Material"
if not exist "%final%" (
    md "%dst%" "%dst%\Downloads" "%dst%\Plans" "%dst%\Quotes" "%dst%\Cut Sheets" "%dst%\Venders" "%final%\2 - Signed Quote - Contract\Non-Current Purchase Orders" "%final%\3 - Special Purchase Trading Goods" "%final%\4 - Engineering\2 - Submittals" "%final%\4 - Engineering\3 - Approvals" "%final%\4 - Engineering\4 - Drawings in Progress\Released Production Drawings" "%final%\5 - Final Production Drawings" "%final%\6 - Q.C. Document" "%final%\7 - Project Management _ Schedule"
    copy /-Y "%dir%\_takeoff.xlsx" "%dst%"
) 
pause
```

- No need for `cls` when running from batch unless the batch is called from somewhere else.
- Moved your starting quotes to the beginning of your `set` variables.
- Fixed `copy /-Y "%dir%\_takeoff.xlsx" %est%` to `%dst%`, since `%est%` isn't set so it's likely copying that `.xlsx` file to your current directory (I would guess you're running the batch from your desktop).
- Put all variables in quotes unless echo'd
- Put all the `mkdir` stuff on one line and used `md` (does the same thing)

Personally, if I were making that many folders I would likely just make each big path a variable prior to any other commands, or I would add each line to a text file like this:

> 1 - Estimating Original Quote Material\Downloads
>   1 - Estimating Original Quote Material\Plans
>   1 - Estimating Original Quote Material\Quotes
>   1 - Estimating Original Quote Material\Cut Sheets
>   1 - Estimating Original Quote Material\Vendors
>   2 - Signed Quote - Contract\Non-Current Purchase Orders
>   3 - Special Purchase Trading Goods
>   4 - Engineering\2 - Submittals
>   4 - Engineering\3 - Approvals
>   4 - Engineering\4 - Drawings in Progress\Released Production Drawings
>   5 - Final Production Drawings
>   6 - Q.C. Document
>   7 - Project Management _ Schedule

and then loop through it to make a folder for each one; that will clean up your block significantly, and if you ever want to tweak something you can just add/remove/modify lines in the text file. It would make the block look like this:

```
@echo off

echo Type The SO number, Customer, and Job named when asked - then press Enter.
echo.
set /p "so=SO #: "
set /p "cus=Customer Name: "
set /p "job=Job Name: "

set "fld=%so%_%cus%_%job%"
echo %fld%

set "dir=F:\Sales\User 1\_QUOTES"
set "fin=%dir%\%fld%"

if not exist "%fin%" (
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%txt%") do (
        md "%fin%\%%A"
    )
    copy /-Y "%dir%\_takeoff.xlsx" "%fin%\1 - Estimating Original Quote Material\%cus%_takeoff.xlsx"
)

pause
```

Reference: [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), [copy](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)

Comment: did you fix the `%est%` part of your script?

Comment: I got it to work. Added an extra space when pasting. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to the answer given, if it's easier for you to read and maintain you could also create directories via a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop), *(with your typo, `Venders`, replaced with `Vendors`)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "dir=F:\Sales\User 1\_QUOTES"
PushD "%dir%" 2>NUL||Exit /B
For %%A In (SO Customer JOB)Do Set "%%A="
ClS
Echo Enter the SO number, Customer and Job name when asked.
Echo(
Set /P "SO #: "
Set /P "Customer=Customer Name: "
Set /P "JOB=Job Name: "
Rem Note: You should perform some input verification here.

Set "final=%SO%_%Customer%_%JOB%"
Echo(%final%
Set "dst=%final%/1 - Estimating Original Quote Material"
For %%A In (
    "%dst%\Downloads"
    "%dst%\Plans"
    "%dst%\Quotes"
    "%dst%\Cut Sheets"
    "%dst%\Vendors"
    "%final%\2 - Signed Quote - Contract\Non-Current Purchase Orders"
    "%final%\3 - Special Purchase Trading Goods"
    "%final%\4 - Engineering\2 - Submittals"
    "%final%\4 - Engineering\3 - Approvals"
    "%final%\4 - Engineering\4 - Drawings in Progress\Released Production Drawings"
    "%final%\5 - Final Production Drawings"
    "%final%\6 - Q.C. Document"
    "%final%\7 - Project Management _ Schedule"   
) Do MD "%%A" 2>NUL
If Not Exist "%dst%\_takeoff.xlsx" If Exist "_takeoff.xlsx" Copy "_takeoff.xlsx" "%dst%"
Pause
```

And once again I'll tell you that you really do need to perform verification and validation of the user input, before blindly trying to use those three variables for creating and propagating all of those directories!

Comment: I know I that i should add user input. However this is just a small script i am making for my self.

Comment: @gizmobrat, it doesn't matter, you've already shown us that you can make typos, it would be foolhardy to not incorporate code to protect your commands or system.

Comment: Point taken. I added this quick and dirty thing that i found, `for /f "delims=1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQURSTVWXYZ" %%a in ("%SO%") do goto :End`

Comment: @gizmobrat, you need to check that the user has entered something first, then you need to verify that what they have entered does not contain invalid characters for  filesystem objects, then ensure that invalid names are not used , including those with trailing spaces or periods etc. It may be simpler for you to check if `%final%` exists, if it does you should be fine, if not try to make it, capture any error and act accordingly. It's also worth noting that just because `%final%` exists does not mean that all of the subdirectories do, hence the reason I've not enclosed it all in an `If Exist`.